# Broadcasting com Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, realtime-database

Estou criando um chat e para isso preciso fazer um modo de real-time para não precisar ficar pingando várias e várias vezes no servidor  `SignalR` que faz esse serviço, estou trabalhando com `Laravel-PHP` e li a documentação [Broadcasting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/broadcasting), porém não estou conseguindo entender como ela funciona.

O que preciso fazer:

Quando um usuário mandar mensagem, o servidor avise o outro usuário que tem mensagem nova, assim evitando milhares de requisições.

Alguém sabe como posso realizar? Que seja uma fuction própria do laravel ou em PHP.

Comment: Da para fazer com laravel porém não é recomendado, melhor maneira é usar websockets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O melhor exemplo que eu já vi é esse
https://pusher.com/tutorials/chat-laravel/

Comment: sim ai ele usa o push obg